# Dynamic IN with cursor

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a dynamic in statement in cursor and in contains a collection of strings:

```
DECLARE @DBs nvarchar(4000)
    SET  @DBs="'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'"

DECLARE CompanyDBCursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT Interid 
    FROM tableName
   WHERE interid  in (@DBs)
```

but it appears an error - Invalid ColumnName

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement for the table you're attempting to select from.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableName](................ ,[INTERID] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,..........)

Comment: Take the double quotes off from around the @DBs="... to start.  Then use single quotes for escaping inside the literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DBs varchar(8000)
        SET  @DBs='aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd'


DECLARE CompanyDBCursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT Interid 
    FROM tableName
   WHERE interid  in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SPLIT(@DBs,','))
```

Here is the table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SPLIT] (
    @str_in VARCHAR(8000),
    @separator VARCHAR(4)
)
RETURNS @strtable TABLE (strval VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Occurrences INT, @Counter INT, @tmpStr VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @Counter = 0
    IF SUBSTRING(@str_in,LEN(@str_in),1) <> @separator 
        SET @str_in = @str_in + @separator

    SET @Occurrences = (DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@str_in,@separator,@separator+'#')) - DATALENGTH(@str_in))/ DATALENGTH(@separator)
    SET @tmpStr = @str_in
    WHILE @Counter <= @Occurrences 
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        INSERT INTO @strtable VALUES ( SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,1,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)-1))
        SET @tmpStr = SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)+1,8000)
        IF DATALENGTH(@tmpStr) = 0
            BREAK
    END
    RETURN 
END
```